# Extra Control Panel Icon on my Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, control-panel

I'm running Windows 7, and I show a second Control Panel in the Taskbar.  I can delete the icon of the 2nd CP, but it will return later.  Any clues to what is going on?

Comment: What happens when you click on it? Is it opening the same things?

Answer (score 0):

On occasion, clicking on it has opened a separate, functioning CP window; usually it is linked to the same CP window as the first CP icon directly under the Network icon.  When attempting to delete the first CP icon from the desktop, clicking 'yes' does not delete it, while the second CP icon can be deleted; it will not reappear until the next log in.  This only occurs logging in as admin, not as a user.  -Max